# Is this function located in a composition injective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Lets say you have a function `Y(x)` which is injective. Now lets say that `Y(Z(x))` is also injective. Is `Z(x)` injective? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_1 \ne x_2$ with $Z(x_1) = Z(x_2)$, and $Z(x_1)$ is in the domain of $Y$, then $Y(Z(x_1)) = Y(Z(x_2))$ so $Y \circ Z$ is not injective.

That bit about domains means it's not necessarily true that $Z$ is injective, unless you specify that the range of $Z$ is contained in the domain of $Y$ (so that $Y \circ Z$ and $Z$ have the same domain).  For example, let $Y(x) = \sqrt(x)$ (defined for $x > 0$) and $Z(x) = -x^2$.  $Y(Z(x)) = \sqrt{-x^2}$ is only defined for $x = 0$, and thus is (trivially) injective on that domain, but $Z$ is not injective on its full domain of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: We are supposed to assume that Y(x) is injective and Y(Z(x)) is injective. How come in the first sentence you say that Y(Z(x)) is not injective?

Comment: Proof by contradiction.